# CUDA 4.1 Update

Tags: gpu, cuda

I'm currently working on porting a particle system to update on the GPU via the use of CUDA. With CUDA, I've already passed over the required data I need to the GPU and allocated and copied the date via the host. When I build the project, it all runs fine, but when I run it, the project says I need to allocate my h_position pointer. This pointer is my host pointer and is meant to hold the data.

I know I need to pass in the current particle position to the required cudaMemcpy call and they are currently stored in a list with a for loop being created and interated for each particle calling the following line of code:

`m_particleList[i].positionY = m_particleList[i].positionY - (m_particleList[i].velocity * frameTime * 0.001f);`

My current host side cuda code looks like this:

```
float* h_position; // Your host pointer. This holds the data (I assume it's already filled with the data.)
    float* d_position; // Your device pointer, we will allocate and fill this
    float* d_velocity;
    float* d_time;
    int threads_per_block = 128; // You should play with this value
    int blocks = m_maxParticles/threads_per_block + ( (m_maxParticles%threads_per_block)?1:0 );
    const int N = 10;
    size_t size = N * sizeof(float);
    cudaMalloc( (void**)&d_position, m_maxParticles * sizeof(float) );
    cudaMemcpy( d_position, h_position, m_maxParticles * sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
```

Both of which were / can be found inside my UpdateParticle() method. I had originally thought it would be a simple case of changing the h_position variable in the cudaMemcpy to m_particleList[i] but then I get the following error:

> no suitable conversion function from
>   "ParticleSystemClass::ParticleType" to "const void *" exists

I've probably messed up somewhere, but could someone please help fix the issues I'm facing. Everything else seems to running fine, it's just when I try to run the program that certain things hit the fan.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any place in your code where you assign anything to h_position, so naturally the CudaMemcpy call fails.

your m_particleList seems to contain ParticleType objects which hold at least position and velocity attributes, not just a single float.

Additionally, do your particles have x,y,z positions and velocities?
You can't just pass the pointer to m_particleList into the CudaMemcpy function then, your list of n ParticleTypes will not fit in an array of n floats.

You might need to create something along the lines of

```
struct particle{
    float x,y,z,vx,vy,vz;
};
```

in both host and device code, and use `particle*` instead of `float*`.

Answer (score 0):

As melak47 has pointed out, the first problem is that you first need to allocate memory for h_position:

```
h_position = malloc(sizeof(float) * m_maxParticles);
memset(h_position, 0, sizeof(float) * m_maxParticles);
```

But it also seems like you're trying to copy back your integrated positions into your particles array on the host?  I really don't recommend copying large amounts of data from the GPU to the CPU every frame.  Only do it if you *absolutely must*.  You haven't mentioned what, if anything, you need to computer on the CPU, but I would say you can just push the particles to the GPU once and let it handle things from there.  To do that, you can declare your particle struct:

```
struct Particle {
    float x, y, z;
    float vx, vy, vz;

    __device__ __host__ Particle() {
        x = 0; y = 0; z = 0;
        vx = 0; vy = 0; vz = 0;
    }
};
```

Prefixing the default constructor with `__device__` and `__host__` indicates that the `Particle` struct can exist on both the CPU and GPU.  Now, you can allocate space for your particles on the CPU, and fill out the information:

```
Particle* particles = malloc(m_maxParticles * sizeof(Particle));
// Fill out positions and initial velocities as you'd like.
```

And then copy the data over to the GPU:

```
Particle* d_particles;
cudaMalloc( (void**)d_particles, m_maxParticles * sizeof(Particle) );
cudaMemcpy( d_particles, particles, m_maxParticles * sizeof(Particle), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice );
```

As I said before, you should probably only do this copy once, unless you are adding or removing particles on a frame-by-frame basis.